# ViewPager, when are child xml files loaded?

Tags: android

Im using this guide to implement a `ViewPager`:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/

This is my `main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
android:background="@drawable/gradientbg" >

 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/viewPager"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My main activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(1);

    //textviews and other controls that arent located in main.xml will be null for a couple of seconds here
```

The viewpager uses 2 child xml files as scrollable content. How do i know when the viewpager is complete so that i can make use of the child control, such as textviews etc?

Hope you get the idea, otherwise ill elaborate. Thanks in advance!

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}

public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    int resId = 0;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        resId = R.layout.debug;
        break;
    case 1:
        resId = R.layout.home;
        break;
    }

    View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);

}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);

}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: Well, your `MyPagerAdapter` creates the views, so it should know when they are created.

Comment: @oxc If `instantiateItem` in MyPagerAdapter has returned 2 views, i can consider it complete? Its only loading 2 child xmls.

Comment: I'd have to see your MyPagerAdapter implementation to comment on that.

Comment: @oxc Allright, updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I prefer to do in this kind of situation is write a custom `View` implementation that keeps references to its children which are initialized at creation. (I often just use inner static classes for that.) This helps to keep things modular.

For example:

```
public class MyView {
  private TextView myTextView;
  private ListView myListView;

  public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, this, true);
    myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
    myListView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_listview);
  }
}
```

You get the drill. Now you could have a `setText(String)` method like:

```
  public void setText(String text) {
    myTextView.setText(text);
  }
```

In your case you would create two such view classes, one `HomeView` and one `DebugView` (or whatever).

You can either create the needed instances beforehand, which seems reasonable if both are being pre-cached by the ViewPager anyway, or you can create them on demand.

The first case (eager instantiation) could look like this:

```
private HomeView homeView;
private DebugView debugView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    homeView = new HomeView(getContext());
    debugView = new DebugView(getContext());

    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(1);
}
```

You do all the needed initialization in the custom View class' constructor, passing the required information (and/or maybe the `savedInstanceState`) as required.

Your PagerAdapter's `instantiateItem` could then look like this:

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    final View view;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
       view = debugView;
       break;
    case 1:
       view = homeView;
       break;
    default:
       throw new IllegalStateException("Should not happen");
    }

    container.addView(view, 0);

    return view;
}
```

(you don't want to use the `instantiateItem(View, int)` method, it's deprecated and unhandy.)

If you want to instantiate your views on-demand, you you would move the constructor call into the adapter, then you will have to check for `null` values when accessing the views.

If you can afford to target API 13 and above, you might want to use a [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) instead.

---

To make things look nicer, if you want a PagerAdapter that just servers a really limited number of views which have been pre-created (which you really only want if it's a very small number like 2), you could write it like this:

```
public class ArrayPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

  private final View[] mViews;

  public ArrayPagerAdapter(View... views) {
      mViews = views;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
      return mViews.length;
  }

  @Override
  public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
      final View view = mViews[position]

      container.addView(view);

      return view;
  }

  @Override
  public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
      container.removeView((View) object);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
      return view == object;
  }

}
```

which you could then instantiate using

```
PagerAdapter adapter = new ArrayPagerAdapter(debugView, homeView);
```